# Why does this app crash with a Runtime error?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

I have an android project which is mostly the template app from android studio. Here is the `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gameStartButton"
        android:text="Start"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_height="@string/mainMenuItemWidth"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here's the `MainActivity.java`:
    package com.example.saga.test;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

When I launch this app, it crashes with this traceback:

```
08-26 17:57:36.256 5868-5868/com.example.saga.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.example.saga.test, PID: 5868
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.saga.test/com.example.saga.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #0: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534)
```

As you can see, I have actually supplied a `layout_height` attribute for both the constraint layout and the button, why then am I getting this error?

Comment: It tells you which is the solution: `You must supply a layout_height attribute.`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a string value for layout_height. Put the value inside dimens.xml and reference that value using

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/mainMenuItemWidth"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Root cause:** You are using a string for property `android:layout_height`. The expected is an `integer` or a `dimen` value.

**Solution:** Create a new file in `res/values` folder called `dimens.xml` then add below section into it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="mainMenuItemWidth">20dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then in your xml file.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/gameStartButton"
        android:text="Start"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/mainMenuItemWidth"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

The app is crashed cause of `android:layout_height="@string/mainMenuItemWidth"` , beacuse `layout_height` is not accept string type value.

create a value in `dimen` file with name of  `mainMenuItemWidth`

Change `android:layout_height="@string/mainMenuItemWidth"` to `android:layout_height="@dimen/mainMenuItemWidth"`

I hope its work for you.